# to whom I talked only once

Tags: grammar, syntax

Below is a sentence I wrote. Not sure if the relative clause here is natural.

> It's rude to call a girl **with whom I had only one talk** by her pet name.

I wonder if it will be better to use a verb here.

> It's rude to call a girl **with whom I talked only once** by her pet name.

Not quite sure where *only* should be put in this sentence, so I came up with another version:

> It's rude to call a girl **with whom I only talked once** by her pet name.

Which one sounds more natural to you? Besides, if you have any other alternatives, please don't hesitate to share them with me.

Comment: Your construction leaves open the possibility that you were talking to someone else - rather than the girl herself - when  you called her by her pet name. You could remove this ambiguity by using **to address** instead of **to call**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are all good efforts and are all grammatical, though the phrase "by her pet name" sounds a little clumsy after the relative clause. I prefer your third option overall.

Although I don't know the context, I suspect the present perfect would be better in the relative clause:

- It's rude to call a girl with whom I have only talked once by her pet name.

A couple of more natural suggestions:

- It's rude to call a girl I've only talked to once by her nickname
- It's rude to call a girl by her nickname when I've only talked to her once
- It's rude calling a girl I've only talked to once by a nickname